# Changed java code has no affect even after restarting wildfly server

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, web-applications, wildfly

I am working on java web application using eclipse with wildfly 20+.

I am debugging an issue on java side, for that I have started wildfly server in Debug mode. I have added some printline inside one method and saved. When I start the application, I can see that my debugger go into that method because i have put breakpoint there but the added printlns and variables inside that methods are not available which means that new changes have no affect. I have also restarted wildfly server and have the same issue. my wilfly configuration looks like this (find attached screenshot):
[image]

What else can I check?

Comment: It's set to "Automatically publish after a build event", so are you letting it Build after you make changes and save the source file to disk?

Comment: @nitind: i also tried automatically publish when resources change but same problem

Comment: That doesn't answer whether you have automatic builds enabled or not. Generally, that's the most reliable option to enable.

Comment: @nitind: yes automatic builds is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Updating code with jpda doesn't work well with WildFly because of the many  classloaders involved. You should use jboss tools for this.

Comment: can you please explain how to solve this issue with jboss tools?